# Code Coverage in python without unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, django-testing, coverage.py, test-coverage

I have a python (Django) application for which I want to generate a code coverage report, but the solutions I have found on the internet mostly work with test runners or requires unit tests for example Coverage.py and pytest-cov. As I don't have unit tests for my code, is there any other options available that can do the coverage for my code without unit tests?

Comment: If you don't have any unit tests, your report will be static and you can write it manually once and will always be true, as your coverage will be 0% :)

Comment: i can not imagine such tool even - how would you like to work? For such tool to work you'd need to track exact code executing, which might be hard or impossible when not in debug mode. And your users most probably get optimized, compiled code in release mode. So I'd say such tool does not exist, but you can write some custom method here and there to check if such method executed and would give you very approximate numbers.

Comment: A profiler would output this kind of information incidentally, but I wouldn't call it coverage; you can't have "test coverage" if you have no tests...

Comment: Agree @MichałTurczyn, Is there any way that can track the behavior of the application while using app and gives the code coverage stats? The application is very big and writing unit tests would require more time. So I'm hunting for some short/automated tool that can be integrated with my code base to track the application's behavior covering each use case and generate code coverage.

Comment: Note that you don't need your tests to be "unit" for a code coverage tool to work; at the end of the day they're all tests, the tools don't really distinguish whether they're "unit" or "integration" or "end-to-end" or whatever...

Comment: You can use `coverage.py` on any python script.  So create a script that exercises your codebase for certain inputs and asserts the end results satisfy whatever conditions you need.